# Calligraphy Drawing IOS Coregraphics

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I am looking to have something which is marked in red, as marker but don't know whether it can be done or not.

It looks like marking using a calligraphy pen.

[image]

Trying out the following code as answered by "Andrey", I get the following output with spaces while drawing.

[image]

Brush image can be found here used is [image]

Making further changes to the code, I found still I am not able to get the expected result.
Here I am trying to fill the path which exists between the current point and the next point.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code


    CGFloat w=5.0;
    CGFloat h=2.0;
    CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

    for(int i=0;i<self.positions.count;i++){
        CGPoint point=[[self.positions objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];

        CGFloat x=point.x-(w/2.0);
        CGFloat y=point.y-(h/2.0);
        CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(x, y, w, h));
        if(i+1<self.positions.count){
            CGPoint nextPoint=[[self.positions objectAtIndex:(i+1)] CGPointValue];
            CGMutablePathRef myPath=CGPathCreateMutable();
            CGPathMoveToPoint(myPath, NULL, x, y);
            CGFloat x1=nextPoint.x-(w/2.0);
            CGFloat y1=nextPoint.y-(h/2.0);

            CGPathAddLineToPoint(myPath, NULL, x1, y1);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(myPath, NULL, w, y1);
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(myPath, NULL, w, y);
            CGPathCloseSubpath(myPath);
            CGContextFillPath(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi bro did you find soultion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those picture can be done via drawing an image in `UIView` subclass with overridden `drawRect:` message. You also need to add some kind of touch handler for catching touches. So here is some code:

```
@interface DrawingView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *positions;

@end

@implementation DrawingView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self awakeFromNib];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.positions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    UIImage *brushImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"brush.png"];
    for (NSValue *object in self.positions) {
        CGPoint point = [object CGPointValue];
        [brushImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(point.x - brushImage.size.width / 2.0, point.y - brushImage.size.height / 2.0)];
    }
}

- (void)addPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    [self.positions addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [self addPoint:[touch locationInView:self]];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [self addPoint:[touch locationInView:self]];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [self addPoint:[touch locationInView:self]];
}

@end
```

You only need to create a proper `brush.png` and place those view anywhere you want.

Comment: Never thought it would be such easy to draw it. Hey by the way when I coded I found there are few spaces left out , this should not occur as we are constantly updating it in touchesMoved:

Comment: @weber67 `touchesMoved` will skip some positions. You have to remember the last position and interpolate positions in between.

Comment: @weber67 you should use some kind of interpolation as Sulthan mentioned above. The proper logic is to implement interpolated line drawing with points you got from touches. But it can be slow with complicated figures.

Comment: You could use lines instead of interpolation though. Just make a color with pattern and draw the line between adjacent points. But it will need some additional logic in `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` to let the figure have spaces. I could correct my answer if you need it :)

Comment: @AndreyChevozerov & Sulthan thanks. I have edit my code, but I found I still have the same results. Please let me know, where i have made mistake.

Comment: @weber67: My idea was to make a color from image through `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:brushImage];` and then draw lines with this color between points.